# Where Can I Find Current Documentation About .NET RIA Services Authentication

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am creating a Silverlight application for our company intranet that uses Windows authentication. I would like to use a authentication domain service class. Where can I find current documentation explaining how to get the authenticated user name etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start is the msdn library. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707361%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) where authentication, roles and profiles are explained and tutorials are provided.